# Is there any safe way to set passwords for a HDD or folder in windows 10 home?

Tags: windows-10, security, passwords, password-management, password-protection

Is there any safe way to set passwords for HDD or a folder in windows 10 home?
The bitlocker is not available in this version. I see some software that allows you to do that but not really sure if it is safe to use.

Comment: You can set a bios password for the computer itself, or just for the drive. These aren't quite as good as using full disk encryption, but would be fine for most purposes.

Comment: You can install VeraCrypt and create a password protected volume. Everything copied into that volume is encrypted and thus secure, if you have chose a secure password.